# Convert/export a Wordpress site on local computer into static content to host a site from s3 bucket

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-s3, static

I am new to web development. I want to make a simple static website (one pager). The plan is to build the website in Wordpress (on my Mac) and export to a static files (like the regular index.html and images) etc of the site and dump them in AWS S3 to host the site. What I am unable to find out - is there a way we can convert this Wordpress site on local computer to static content. Please let me know how we can achieve it.

Also, if you can let me know if there are any other ways apart from Wordpress that I can do to achieve the same effect that will be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this might work: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget

Comment: Why would you start with Wordpress for this if you know you don't want to host the site with Wordpress? Why not start with something built to generate static sites like Jekyll or Hugo?